# Apply bg_color for select rows without changing other format settings - (Python, xlsxwriter)

Tags: python, formatting, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I'm currently working on formatting a dataframe to a desired format xlsx file.
I give some formats to certain columns already using xlsxwriter (like two decimal places and currency) as follows:

```
worksheet.set_column(col_idx, col_idx, None, cell_format=workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00%'}))
```

My next step is to set a bg_color to some rows but If I do:

```
sel_color = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#B9D1F4'})
worksheet.set_row(row, cell_format=sel_color)
```

It will overwrite the formats I set in columns

Can I please ask if there is anything I can do for this?

Comment: There isn't an easy way to do this. If a row and column format intersect in Excel they create a combined third format. In XlsxWriter you need to create and apply this third format explicitly to get the same effect.

Comment: I solved this by using conditional_formatting from xlsxwrtier. It seems that this function can add more format into cells without overwritting. \